# Parenting Objects to Animation Node Object Instances

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to animate this city scene so the tiles filp over and reveal a house or a building on the other side. I was able to get the tiles in the correct location and flip over and I was able to have the house objects and trees follow it by parenting it to the tile. It worked great, however after I loaded the file again all of the parenting was removed. Is there a way to keep the parent information after re-loading the file? I am using Blender 2.8 and Animation Nodes 2.14. Thanks.

[image: City Blender Scene]
[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Did you do the parenting manually? Are there multiple objects parented to a single tile? Have you tried doing the transformation directly to the objects as well?

Comment: Yes I did the parenting manually and there were multiple objects parented to a single tile. How would I go about applying the transformation to the parented objects as well and still retain the animation style I had with using a null to act as the falloff parameter? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The *Object Instancer* node dynamically add and remove objects on demand. So anything you do on the object is not persistent. The obvious solution here is create the the parent objects manually and do the parenting as you did. Then add those parents to a collection, get the collection's objects, get their transformation matrices, and offset them based on the target falloff just as you did.